# Does the pyorbital.get_position function output position vectors in the ECEF or ECI frame?

Tags: python, satellite, orbital-mechanics

The documentation for this function surprisingly doesn't mention the coordinate frame. Does anyone know which it is? Thanks!
https://pyorbital.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#pyorbital.orbital.Orbital.get_position

Answer (score 0):

I took a quick peek at the source code at https://github.com/pytroll/pyorbital/blob/main/pyorbital/orbital.py. They are just using the output from SGP4, so the coordinate frame is going to be TEME of Date. It also looks like they have their own implementation of SGP4. I can't tell at a glance whether it includes the various tweaks that Vallado et. al. had implemented to get the open source version to more closely match the "official" version (see https://celestrak.org/publications/AIAA/2006-6753/AIAA-2006-6753.pdf).

Comment: Pyorbital dev here: the implementation of the sgp4 algorithm we have is just a python translation of the Vallado one indeed.